# Changing the values of an instance of a class through another class in python

Tags: python

I have the classes `Employee` and `Company`

```
class Company:

    employee_list = [
    {"name":"rohan", "salary" : 50000, "number" : "9243485233", "working_days" : 300, "bonus" : "30%"}
    ]

    def give_leaves(self, name, leaves_required):
        if leaves_required < 5:
            working_days = self.employee_list[0].get("working_days")
            working_days -= leaves_required
            self.employee_list[0]["working_days"] = working_days
            print(self.employee_list)
        else:
            print("Leaves can't be granted")

class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name, salary, number):
        self.working_days = 300
        self.bonus_percent = 30
        self.name = name
        self.salary_dollars = salary
        self.number = number

    def ask_for_leaves(self):
        try:
            leaves_required = int(input("How many days off are required?"))
            print("Request sent to Company.")
            Company.give_leaves(Company, self.name, leaves_required)
        except ValueError:
            pass


rohan = Employee("rohan", 50000, "9243485233")
rohan.ask_for_leaves()
```

When granting the `Employee` instance `rohan` leaves, and updating the `working_days` in the `employee_list`, I would like to also change the instance attribute `working_days` of `rohan`

Comment: What's the issue? What do you want your code to do?

Comment: company doesn't know about `Employee rohan` object, but only because you hard-coded inside the class...

Comment: you have mess in code. You use `Company` as first agument but you should rathre create instance `c = Company()` and send it as argument to instance of `Employee` - `rohan = Employee(..., c)`. Other mess: Inside `Company` you keep some information about `rohan` - you have to decide if you want to keep it inside `Company` and create `Employee` inside `Company`, or keep all outsife company and send company as parameter to `Employee`

Comment: ok, I will think about this desgin flaw

Comment: @MohammadTehrani I would like my code to auto-update ```Employee``` attributes, when the attributes of that instance are changed in the ```employee_list```. I thought this was quite clear from my question? If it wasn't, please edit my question to make it more acessible, or let me know the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add instance of `Employee` to `employee_list` - and this way you don't duplicate data.

You should rather create instance of class `Company` and send it to `Employee` and it should add itself to list `employee_list`.

```
    # add company to employee
    self.company = company

    # add employee to company
    self.company.employee_list.append(self)
```

And later `Employee` can use `self.company` to access functions in Company. And `Company` can use list `employee_list` to access infromation in every `Employee`

---

```
class Company:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.employee_list = []

    def give_leaves(self, employee, leaves_required):
        if leaves_required < 5:
            if employee.working_days >= leaves_required:
                employee.working_days -= leaves_required
                print('Working days:', employee.working_days)
            else:
                print('You don\'t have working days')
        else:
            print("Leaves can't be granted")

    def list(self):
        print(f'--- employees in {self.name} ---')
        if not self.employee_list:
            print('No employees')
        else:
            for employee in self.employee_list:
                print('name:', employee.name, '| working days:', employee.working_days)
            
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary, number, company):
        self.working_days = 300
        self.bonus_percent = 30
        self.name = name
        self.salary_dollars = salary
        self.number = number
        
        # add company to employee
        self.company = company

        # add employee to company
        self.company.employee_list.append(self)

    def ask_for_leaves(self, leaves_required):
        try:
            print("Request sent to Company.")
            # send itself as first argument - so it will have direct access to data
            self.company.give_leaves(self, leaves_required)
        except ValueError as ex:
            print('Exception:', ex)

# --- main ---

company = Company('MI6')
company.list()

rohan = Employee("rohan", 50000, "9243485233", company)
james_bond = Employee("james_bond", 500_000, "007", company)
company.list()

days = int(input("How many days off are required? "))
rohan.ask_for_leaves(days)
company.list()
```

Result:

```
--- employees in  MI6 ---
No employees

--- employees in  MI6 ---
name: rohan | working days: 300
name: james_bond | working days: 300

How many days off are required? 4
Request sent to Company.
Working days: 296

--- employees in  MI6 ---
name: rohan | working days: 296
name: james_bond | working days: 300
```

Comment: Wow thank you, I did not know that instances of a class could be created inside another class.

Comment: in this code I create all instances outside other classes and I only send instances to other classes. But you can also in `Company` create function which gets all information about user and create instance `Employee` inside `Company` (and returns this instance)

Comment: But just wondering, is there a possible solution where you do not give full control of the company to the employee, as that is not something that would happen in actuality

Comment: so I could give company control of employee? I think that would be better, I will try to implement it based on your current solution

Comment: Hey, I tried implementing this kind of solution with an additional ```apply_in_company``` function, and the code works perfectly, thanks